# Security of authentication check for a blog

Tags: php, security, database, authentication

I am currently making a very big blogging system for my Website where I want really neat code! So, I was wondering: is this method safe/does it have any problems with security? Yes, I'll be encrypting the password anyway. I also want to know if there is a better way to achieve the same idea. Also any tips on implementing high security and high performance?

```
<?php
class Users {
    protected $db;
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $lastlogin;
    public $email;
    public $rank;
    public $creationdate;
    public $country;
    public $status;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'php123', 'ht');
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM blog_users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
        $query->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($username, $password);
        $query->store_result();
        if($query->num_rows == 1) {
            while($query->fetch()) {
                $userData = getData($username);

                $this->id             =   $this->userData['id'];
                $this->username       =   $username;
                $this->password       =   $password;
                $this->lastlogin      =   time();
                $this->email          =   $this->userData['email'];
                $this->rank           =   $this->userData['rank'];
                $this->creationdate   =   $this->userData['creationdate'];
                $this->country        =   $this->userData['country'];
                $this->status         =   $this->userData['status'];

                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        $query->close();
        $query->free_result();
    }

    public function getData($username) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, email, rank, creationdate, country, status FROM blog_users WHERE username = ?");
        $query->bind_param('s', $username);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($id, $email, $rank, $creationdate, $country, $status);
        $query->store_result();
        $userData = array(
            'id'           => $id,
            'email'        => $email,
            'rank'         => $rank,
            'creationdate' => $creationdate,
            'country'      => $country,
            'status'       => $status
        );
        return $userData;
        $query->close();
        $query->free_result;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Please read the help section of this site: you are asked to post actual, working code... the constructor you've posted _can't possibly work!_. `$this->db = $db;` when `$db` is not in scope, typo's: (like `eles` instead of `else`). Debug your code first, before you can get it reviewed

Comment: $db is outside the class. I'll fix it still.

Comment: I've seen the `$db`, but still: the code, as posted here, doesn't work. You are required to post working code to get a review here. That was my point

Comment: Ok, updated. Every script I code is the same way, so it is 100% working.

Comment: Nope, it can't be working as you expect it to: in your `login` method, there's a call to the `getData` method, but you wrote `getData($username);` when it should've been `$this->userName`

Comment: Why are you so harsh? :l Won't work.. won't work.. won't work... You can always point out errors. Actually, I thought CodeReview at StackExchange was actually good, but CodeReview is also filled with big headed people who think they're the best.

Comment: Well, that's because, IMO codereview has to be tough, to be good. [I've explained my viewpoints on the matter here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/810/guidelines-for-new-users-proposal-tag). It's important to keep in mind that, though critiques can be harsh, the only thing we (the people reviewing your code) are trying to do, is to _help_ you, not to hurt you

Comment: Ok, like I'm a human, I make mistakes. I'm learning PHP since a fair amount of time. But, now I guess that if you could tell me the best way to code what I have coded, and is it at all safe when it comes to security?

Comment: On the safety front: I can't give you a definitive answer, simply because I don't know how this code is going to be used. And a lot of it depends on your server settings. Is it the best way to code what you need? IMO: no, but it's a start

Comment: I’m concerned by you using the word “encrypt” for your passwords. What is your intended security scheme for passwords? Do you know what bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDF2 are, do you know the difference between a hash and a cipher? If not, I’m happy to provide some resources, because then this is a desaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I am using 000webhost as I've got no bucks, and it doesn't support bcrypt. Can you provide me some good encryption functions supported in PHP Version 5.2.*

Comment: @HassanAlthaf: There are many, free and open libs to use blowfish in PHP<5.3 [there's a link in the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637445/to-use-crypt-blowfish-on-php-5-2-that-doesnt-support-it)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I found out that PBKDF2 is better than BCrypt I decided to use PBKDF2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, just a few quick thoughts, will be adding to this answer later today (ie after work):

***One class, One task***
Chances are, you've already heard of the SOLID principles. Well, here they are again: your code is in violation of the SRP (Single Responsability principle). A class has one task. No more, no less. Your class does 4 things: it stores data (all those public properties), messes with sessions, connects to the DB *and* performs queries.
The Database connection and queries are all things that should be dealt with in another class, that simply connects to the DB and executes queries.

This other class could then have a method like this:

```
public function login(User $user)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM blog_users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
    $query->bind_param('ss', $user->username, $user->password);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($user->username, $user->password);
    $query->store_result();
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $query->fetch();
        $query->close();
        return $this->getUserData($user);//changed name of method
    }
    $query->close();
    throw new RuntimeException('User can not login');//error
}
```

Even this isn't close to efficient code, because it still calls a second method to, basically, repeat the same query. Why would you do so, why not simply write:

```
public function login(User $user)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare(
        "SELECT id, email, rank, creationdate,
            country, status, username, password
        FROM blog_users
        WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1"
    );
    $query->bind_param('ss', $user->username, $user->password);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result(
        $user->id,
        $user->email,
        $user->rank,
        $user->creationdate,
        $user->country,
        $user->status,
        $user->username,
        $user->password
    );
    $query->store_result();
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $query->fetch();
        $query->free_result();//call free_result...
        $query->close();//and close here, too: your code doesn't do this
        return $user;
    }
    $query->free_result();
    $query->close();
    throw new RuntimeException('User can not login');//error
}
```

Isn't that a lot shorter, clearer and doesn't this also do *exactly* what you are doing? K.I.S.S!

***Classes with a dependency, should be open to injection***
Your current code is hard to test: the constructor connects to the DB, there is no way for me (the user), or you (when testing) to mock the db connection, or use a bogus testing table.
The best way to make your class easier to test it to allow the user to pass a specific connection to the constructor, and then he can use your class/functionality to work on the db of his choice:

```
public function __construct(mysqli $connection = null)
{//default null means the argument is optional
    if ($connection === null)
        $connection = new mysqli();//connect to default
    $this->db = $connection;//use connection we've created, or the one the user passed through to the constructor
}
```

And of course: a DB connection that is opened, should be closed: when your class dies (is destructed), the DB connection should die, too:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->db->close();
    $this->db = null;
}
```

That should be added to your code, too. If you don't then the connection will be kept open until your script has terminated, which could be longer than you want. If performance and cleanliness matter to you, then this should be a habit.

***Standards, coding style***
Yes, I complain/nag a lot about coding style and standards but if you are, like you say, creating a sizeable code-base, then you should know that coding style and standards are *insanely important*.
The unofficial PHP standards can be found [here](http://www.php-fig.org). Though unofficial, all major players (ie Zend, Symfony, Cake, Doctrine, ...) all subscribe to them.

***Other niggles***:
Your class has tons of properties, and it's those properties that you are assigning in the methods. Why, then aren't you assigning `$username` as soon as you can, so you don't have to pass it to the `getData` method as an argument?

Another remark I have is simply this:
If a script contains *only* PHP code, then that script should not have a closing `?>` tag. Get rid of it.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf: No, the other way around: the `User` class should be a simple data container. That data can be passed around from the core (the model layer, or the place where your logic resides... whatever you call it), all the way through to the view. The DB connection should not be passed to the view. Ever. This DB class should have methods like `findUser(User $user)`, to which you pass this Data object, and it's that class that queries and returns new `User` instances

Comment: Are you talking about Model View Controller? And I'm seriously impressed on the Namespaces, can you give me a good beginner tutorial on them? I think they'll be seriously useful for me.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf: I'm not really talking about MVC (not as such, anyways), just common sense: `User` represents a `User`'s data, so it shouldn't perform queries. Either way, though unrelated, [Here's an answer on IoC and DI I've posted a while back](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38312/understanding-dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control/38320#38320). If you want to learn about namespaces, then [this is all you really have to know](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), and then experiment, because they can indeed be useful in larger projects

Comment: Yes, my project is going to be a large one! Would you like to stay on touch with me via Skype?